# GraphQL field-level validation in AppSync

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I have an AppSync API that's mostly backed by a DynamoDB store. Most of the resolvers are hooked up directly to the DynamoDB sources, not using lambdas.

Some of the fields should have validation constraints, such as length or a regexp. In one particular case I would like to require that a `state` field contain an ISO 3166-2 value like `US-NY`. (GraphQL enums values can't contain hyphens, so that isn't an option here.)

Other than replacing some resolvers with lambdas, the only way I can think of to apply these sorts of validation rules is to do it in VTL in the `RequestMappingTemplate`. That would work, but it would be tedious and likely result in duplicate code. Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, only way without lambda is VTL , I suggest that instead of writing validation directly inside `RequestMappingTemplate`, using pipeline resolver.(less duplicated)

> **Pipeline Resolvers** contain one or more Functions which are executed in order.
>
> **Functions** allow you to write common logic for reuse across multiple Resolvers in your schema. They are attached directly to a data source and like a Unit resolver, contain the same request and response mapping template format.

You can find a good example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/pipeline-resolvers.html).